# Flexbox Orientation Change Width / Height Issues

Tags: ios, css, flexbox

I am attempting to use flexbox to achieve a series of sections that fill 100% width and height of the viewport. This works perfectly on desktop without any issues when resizing the browser window. On mobile however, whenever I change the orientation, the section sizing does not adjust correctly.

I have made a pen of my issue:

http://codepen.io/beefchimi/full/LlInw/

The flexbox css is:

```
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
section {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
article {
    margin: auto;
}
```

I believe my implementation is correct... but I'm very surprised to see iOS not behaving as expected. Any suggestions on solving this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: why are you using flexbox for this? you can achieve the same with legacy css

Comment: I know of a technique using display: table / table-cell, but unfortunately that does not work for my particular use case. The table approach does not allow me to use $(window).scrollTop(); If you can provide a better solution to this layout problem, I could welcome that as an answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is an iOS 6 - 7 bug. More information can be found here:

https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/36

The github issue thread suggests a js plugin:

https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill

For my particular case, I simply implemented my own bit of jQuery that will measure the window height on window load, apply that value to all sections, then track the window height during window resize and reapply. An unfortunate work around :(

```
var $window      = $(window),
    $sections    = $('section'),
    windowHeight;

function adjustHeight() {

    // get height of browser window on page load and resize events
    windowHeight = $window.height();

    // apply windowHeight to each <section>
    $sections.height(windowHeight);

}

$window.resize(function() {
    adjustHeight();
});

$window.load(function() {
    adjustHeight();
});
```

Comment: A bug that still hasnt been addressed in the latest ios version.. great, just great.